# symfony-docker fails building Symfony project

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I am trying to Dockerize my Symfony project. I have cloned the [symfony-docker skeleton](https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker) to my project folder. I followed the procedures in the [guidelines](https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/blob/main/docs/existing-project.md) until the where I have to build the container image with `docker compose build --no-cache --pull`. But, I get the following error:

```
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c xcaddy build       --with github.com/dunglas/mercure       --with github.com/dunglas/mercure/caddy        --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain        --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain/caddy]: exit code: 1
```

Here's the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/blob/main/Dockerfile) I am using. Nothing changed. What am I missing? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by upgrading to a newer version of caddy.
I replaced in Dockerfile

```
FROM caddy:2.6-builder-alpine
```

to

```
FROM caddy:2.7-builder-alpine
```

and it worked.